# Yocto: bitbake command to regenerate all RPM files

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, rpm, yocto, bitbake

I wanted to make some free space and deleted all directories in build/tmp/deploy/rpm/, thinking yocto would detect it and recreate them at the next bitbake  call... it was a mistake ! :(

Here's the bitbake error just in case:

```
bitbake <image_name>
[...]
ERROR: ... do_rootfs: minicom not found in the base feeds (<image_name> corei7-64-intel-common corei7-64 core2-64 x86_64 noarch any all).
[...list of every package...]
```

Is there any way to force the regeneration of every rpms using bitbake ?
Forcing the regeneration with `bitbake -f -c package_write_rpm <package>` works, but I didn't find the command to do it all at once.

I tried cleaning the state of the native rpm packages thinking it might detect it and invalidate the rpm files states, but no luck:

```
bitbake -f -c cleanall nativesdk-rpm nativesdk-rpmresolve rpmresolve-native rpm-native
bitbake <image_name>
```

I also thought this would work, but it didn't:

```
bitbake -f -c package_write_rpm <image_name>
```

I will try to hack something with `bitbake-layers show-recipes` and  `xargs`, but it would be cool to have a proper bitbake command.

I am using Yocto 2.1 (Krogoth).

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing the following script and use bitbake dependency tree to get the list of packages (thanks to this [yocto/bitbake reference page](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-94953)):

```
# bitbake -g <image> && cat pn-depends.dot | grep -v -e '-native' | grep -v digraph | grep -v -e '-image' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | grep -v "}" | grep -v cross | grep -v gcc | grep -v glibc > packages-list.txt
# cat packages-list.txt | xargs bitbake -f -c package_write_rpm
```

Maybe there is a more straightforward solution ? For now this worked.